# Duda sobre jquery

Tags: jquery

Hace tiempo tengo la duda de como es mejor establecer las funciones de jquery, ademas de una duda curiosa:

En ciertas partes del programa que estoy realizando llamo a los elementos por ejemplo así:

```
$(document).on('click', '.accountNotification', function(){
   alert("lalala");
});
```

y esto funciona perfectamente pero sin embargo en otras partes no me funciona y me veo obligado a llamarlo así:

```
$('#finishProjectOption').on('click', function(){
   alert("holi");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Por lo que yo entiendo, en el primer caso ***enlazas el controlador del evento con el documento*** y le dices que, cuando pulsen sobre el documento, cualquier elemento que corresponda con el selector que le has indicado, **esté o no** el DOM en el momento de definir el controlador, responda al mismo

En cambio, en el segundo caso ***enlazas directamente el controlador con los elementos*** que cumplan el selector y que **estén** en el DOM en ese momento en el momento de definir el controlador

El problema que tienes con el primer caso podría deberse a que se haya detenido la propagación del evento en algún punto (*stopPropagation*)